# Multiple pages with same URL in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that has a standard Page called Places with URL

```
example.com/places/
```

And I have several child Pages called by cities

```
example.com/places/city-1
example.com/places/city-2
```

Now, I have a custom post type `Place` that should indicate a single place and should have permalink like

```
example.com/places/place-1
```

But then if I go to one of the previous links with city-1, city-2 I get 404 obviously because there is no `place` with that permalink.

Is there a way for WordPress to drop to previous permalink. So if there is no `place` with that name, look for a `page` with it.

Comment: The way routing works won't allow this. It's basically a list of regex patterns and in your case they overlap, thus the one that's first in the list will match. Custom post type patterns are added at the beginning of this list. The only way you can make this work would be to add a custom route/pattern and handle it yourself, deciding what to display. So look into `add_rewrite_rule`, catch that route in a plugin and then set the global `$wp_query` to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the the `REFERER`-value from the [PHP server variable](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php) `$_SERVER`, but it´s not very reliable and can be altered.

I am using [the plugin "Permalink Finder"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-finder/) in one of the pages I am maintaining and that works quite well for finding changed URL. You could give it a try and see if it works for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody ever having a similar problem, it can be done by using verbose page rules. This is an example I found at WordPress Stack Exchange
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22438/how-to-make-pages-slug-have-priority-over-any-other-taxonomies-like-custom-post

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse16902_init' );
function wpse16902_init() {
    $GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']->use_verbose_page_rules = true;
}

add_filter( 'page_rewrite_rules',     'wpse16902_collect_page_rewrite_rules' );
function wpse16902_collect_page_rewrite_rules( $page_rewrite_rules )
{
    $GLOBALS['wpse16902_page_rewrite_rules'] = $page_rewrite_rules;
    return array();
}

add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array',     'wspe16902_prepend_page_rewrite_rules' );
function wspe16902_prepend_page_rewrite_rules( $rewrite_rules )
{
    return $GLOBALS['wpse16902_page_rewrite_rules'] + $rewrite_rules;
}
```